# bash array loop is not returning correct elements

Tags: arrays, json, bash, api

This is my script.sh:

```
emails=$(curl -X GET http://0.0.0.0:5000/v1/user/all | jq 'map(.[].email)')
echo $emails
for email in ${emails[@]}
do
  echo $email
  FROM=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T")
  TO=$(date -d "$today -1 month" "+%Y-%m-%d %T")
  SEND=true
  JSON_STRING='{"email":"'"$email"'","from":"'"$FROM"'","to":"'"$TO"'","send":"'"$SEND"'"}'
  curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:5000/v1/invoice/print -d JSON_STRING
done
```

The emails data i get from the first API call is the following:

```
["email1@gmail.com", "email2@gmail.com", "email3@qbknowsfq.com"]
```

the API POST curl does this:

```
{"email":"[","from":"2022-03-28 09:59:06","to":"2022-02-28 09:59:06","send":"true"}
{"message": "Internal Server Error"}
{"email":""email1@gmail.com",","from":"2022-03-28 09:59:06","to":"2022-02-28 09:59:06","send":"true"}
{"message": "Internal Server Error"}
{"email":""email2@gmail.com",","from":"2022-03-28 09:59:06","to":"2022-02-28 09:59:06","send":"true"}
{"message": "Internal Server Error"}
{"email":""email3@qbknowsfq.com",","from":"2022-03-28 09:59:06","to":"2022-02-28 09:59:06","send":"true"}
{"message": "Internal Server Error"}
{"email":"]","from":"2022-03-28 09:59:07","to":"2022-02-28 09:59:07","send":"true"}
{"message": "Internal Server Error"}
```

edit: the scripts echo return:

```
["email1@gmail.com", "email2@gmail.com", "email3@qbknowsfq.com"]
[
{"email":"[","from":"2022-03-28 09:59:06","to":"2022-02-28 09:59:06","send":"true"}
{"message": "Internal Server Error"}
"email1@gmail.com",
{"email":""email1@gmail.com",","from":"2022-03-28 09:59:06","to":"2022-02-28 09:59:06","send":"true"}
{"message": "Internal Server Error"}
"email2@gmail.com",
{"email":""email2@gmail.com",","from":"2022-03-28 09:59:06","to":"2022-02-28 09:59:06","send":"true"}
{"message": "Internal Server Error"}
"email3@qbknowsfq.com",
{"email":""email3@qbknowsfq.com",","from":"2022-03-28 09:59:06","to":"2022-02-28 09:59:06","send":"true"}
{"message": "Internal Server Error"}
]
{"email":"]","from":"2022-03-28 09:59:07","to":"2022-02-28 09:59:07","send":"true"}
{"message": "Internal Server Error"}
```

I don't understand why the emails loop is treating the parentheses [ and ] and returning ' "email@gmail.com",' instead of just 'email@gmail.com'? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you include the messages from your two echoes? I'm surprised the `jq` output isn't handled as a single string if it's indeed a single-line JSON array as you posted. Anyway, bash doesn't understand JSON arrays. You'll have to use `jq`'s `--raw-output` and possibly add a `[]` at the end of your command to have `jq` output every item of the array on its own line, at which point this line-separated output will be easily parsable by bash

Comment: @Aaron I added the echo messages, the emails data I posted is actually what jq returns, since it's supposed to return a string I guess I'm looping through it the wrong way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the output you're getting from `jq` :

```
[
    "email1@gmail.com",
    "email2@gmail.com",
    "email3@qbknowsfq.com",
]
```

bash-wise, it's not an array, it's a multi-line string.

Indexing it with `[@]` changes nothing and returns the whole string. Iterating over it with `for var in $multiline_string` executes the code for each space-separated token of the string. Since your emails do not contain spaces, that's for each line of the string.

You need to have `jq` produce a space-separated list of email addresses without quotes for bash to process them easily. Just change your jq command into the following :

```
jq -r 'map(.[].email)[]'
```

Comment: I tried this and got `jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot iterate over string ("email..)` what fixed it was doing `jq -r '.. | strings'`, choosing this as the answer because it helped me understand my mistake.

Comment: @CyrineG I'd need to have your input JSON to be sure, but the `[]` should be outside of `map` I think. See my test [here](https://jqplay.org/s/AfXucfbLxn) if you want to try it with your data.

Comment: Yes with `[ ]` outside `map`, it works! Thank you!